# SVG generator with animations

Tags: css, svg

I'm searching for software to generate SVG and CSS3 (for animations) code.
I already know lots of tools that exports to SVG and JavaScript (sometimes also CSS3 + JavaScript), but I'm looking for generator that returns pure SVG + CSS3 code. I saw lots of docs and tried some examples and I know that it's possible to create SVG and animate it with `@keyframes` rules and `animation` property in CSS3.

An fallback `apng` export would be great, but not required if there are no better tools.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Web Designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/) might fit your criteria. Failing that look at [Inkscape Animation](https://inkscape.org/sk/learn/animation/)

Comment: firstly it's a beta release - I would like to work on stable software :/, secondly I can't find a SVG option, I see ads, HTML (with canvas), CSS, JavaScript and XML but this topic is about SVG element + CSS animations

Comment: oh, and I forgot to write about second link, if I understand all descriptions then there are a list of programs that could work with SVG and only tutorials to combine SVG and CSS3 - I'm looking for complete SVG editor to work with CSS3 animations, because lots of JavaScript plug-ins provices functionally that could be done in CSS (not all, but JavaScript part I can done manually - most of work I will have with animations).

Comment: What do you mean by "complete SVG editor to work with CSS3 animations"? SVG and CSS are both stored as text, and you can edit that using an ordinary text editor such as Microsoft's Notepad. I suspect that's not what you want though, because it would not be easy to code your animation directly by editing these files.

I've looked for SVG/CSS-based animation tools. I didn't find exactly what I wanted, so am writing my own. But the best I did find was SVGator, https://www.svgator.com/ . Is that any use to you? I don't think it's free, but you didn't say whether you needed that.